# Undefined module when commands are grouped

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I’m doing a discord bot and decided to group my commands in separate files like help.js is one command and ping.js is another for example. Though now the problem is that the command cant find the module and so the code gives me an error like:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: ms is not defined
```

Even though I have it defined in the top of the index file. (ms is a module that I need in my mute command to convert time)

```
const ms = require(“ms”);
```

I use this to get the commands:

```
   try {
    if (fs.existsSync(`./commands/${command}.js`)) {

    let commandFile = require(`./commands/${command}.js`);

      commandFile.run(client, message, args);
    } else {
      message.reply(`+${command} does not exist`)
    }
```

And here is the ping command for example:

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args, level) => { 
  const m = await message.channel.send("Ping?");
  m.edit(`Pong! Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp -message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
}
```

I have checked that I have the node modules installed.

My question is, what am I doing wrong, why is it doing this & what do I do to fix this?

Comment: You have to import / require it *at every single file* you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to require it in every file you have, unless it won't be available for you. You can also export it but you still need to import the main file and use it from there.

Comment: Yes thank you that helped. I also noticed that you have to do the same with functions. Very much thanks for the help.